# To focus last row in datagrid by devexpress angular

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress

i want to focus the last row that is added in datagrid by devexpress.
I used focusedRowEnabled and focusedRowIndex property and set it to dataaray.length-1 but it focuses second last row .Please suggest.

```
            (onEditorPreparing)="onEditorPreparing($event)" keyExpr="ID" [showColumnLines]="false"
            [showRowLines]="false" [hoverStateEnabled]="true" [showBorders]="true" [rowAlternationEnabled]="false"
            [columnAutoWidth]="true" [wordWrapEnabled]="true" [focusedRowEnabled]="true" [focusedRowIndex]="data_array.length-1"
             (onRowUpdating)="logEvent('RowUpdating')"
             (onRowRemoving)="logEvent('RowRemoving')"  (onCellPrepared)="onCellPrepared($event)"
            (onRowRemoved)="logEvent('RowRemoved')" (onSaving)="logEvent('Saving')" (onSaved)="logEvent('Saved')"
            (onEditCanceling)="logEvent('EditCanceling')" (onEditCanceled)="logEvent('EditCanceled')" (useIcons)="true">
            <dxo-editing mode="cell" [allowUpdating]="true" [allowDeleting]="true" [allowAdding]="false">
            </dxo-editing>
```

Comment: It works fine for me, check if you are creating any row manually, like a filtering row or something else!